# Entity Framework defaultconnectionfactory-- not working-- the apps shows --ApplicationException: No database instance

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

Here is my `web.config`, it is showing no database instance. Not sure if I missed something.

The database is SQL Server 2014 Standard edition

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory,       EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServer" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" 
             invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" 
             description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" 
             type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOmiL.png)

Can anyone help me? It is working fine with another Azure VM, when I deploy it to a new Azure VM, it is not working. Maybe I missed something?